# Is it possible to calculate angular acceleration from a measured linear acceleration?

Tags: kinematics, rotational-kinematics

I am trying to use an accelerometer to measure the angular acceleration of a robotic arm.

From rigid body kinematics, the following relation is known

\begin{align*} {^{i} {\boldsymbol{a}}_m} & = {^{i} {\boldsymbol{a}}_l} + ^{i} \dot{{\boldsymbol{\omega }}}_{i} \times {^{i} {{\boldsymbol{X}}}_{S_m}} + {^{i} {{\boldsymbol{\omega }}}_{i}} \times \left({^{i} {{\boldsymbol{\omega }}}_{i}} \times {^{i} {{\boldsymbol{X}}}_{S_m}} \right) \;  \end{align*}

where $\dot{\omega}$ is the angular acceleration and $ {^{i} {\boldsymbol{a}}_m}$ is the measured acceration at a point $X$ along the arm.

The problem is that this equation is not solvable for $\dot{\omega}$ because, it's in a cross product with the position vector of the sensor. ($a \times (b +ka) = a \times b + k(a \times a) = a \times b$)

This [paper](https://doi.org/10.1109/IROS40897.2019.8968475) claims that they used an extended Kalman filter and this relation to estimate the angular acceleration, but I have no idea how that is possible when this equation does not have a unique solution for $\dot{\omega}$.

Can anyone point out if I'm missing something which can help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear on what your equation indicates or exactly what your accelerometer is measuring, but if you  need an angular acceleration for an arm, that could be only horizontal or vertical or a vector sum  of the two. In each case α = a/r.

Comment: The equation relates the acceleration of of 2 points of a rigid body. $\alpha = a/r$ works for the 2 dimensional case, but I'm having trouble finding a similar relation in 3d. The accelerometer measures linear acceleration, and I'm trying to service what rotational acceleration is causing this linear acceleration

Comment: An (upper) arm can only pivot about the shoulder.  That motion can be described in terms of two components. If there is a lower arm, it pivots about the elbow. The two parts should be described separately.